# OnActivityResult doesn't update ImageView in Android

Tags: android, onactivityresult

In my app I have set image in activity called Day. Now, when the user wants to change the image he choses the button and selects the image from Gallery. Here is the code :

```
private void choosePhoto() {
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK);
}
```

When user selects image, I catch in onActivityResult, what he chose, and want to set it as new ImageView, but it doesn't update. I mean, the old image is still visible, but not the new one. I have to quit and enter to activity again to see the change. 
Here is onActivityResult :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String realImagePath = PhotoUtils.getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
        Bitmap imageBitmap = PhotoUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(dayPhoto, realImagePath);
        dbAdapter.setDayImage(realImagePath, dayOfMonth, month, year);
        dayPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);  // this doesn't work, the image is not updated
    }
}
```

Comment: `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(dayPhoto, realImagePath);` ? Why is your ImageView dayPhoto used in this function? `dbAdapter.setDayImage(realImagePath,` Please explain what is happening here.

Comment: dayPhoto is just needed to get height and width. setDayImage is setting this image to database, anyway, I have solved the problem. Posting it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below code after `dayPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);`

```
 dayPhoto.invalidate();
```

Comment: so i think `PhotoUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(dayPhoto, realImagePath);` may have some issues and the `imageBitmap` is not the new one.

Comment: I have just debugged and realImagePath has correct path. Also if at first my `ImageView` is blank (has default image set) and then user chooses the photo from gallery, it works. But when I want to override with another image it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setImageDrawable` as follows:

```
dayPhoto.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(imageBitmap));
```

Comment: Tried also with dayPhoto.invalidate(), but still doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, which was somewhere else.

I needed to use `onWindowsFocusChanged` method to setImageBitmap, because I couldn't do it in onCreate method.

So my code was :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_day);

    initializeLayoutAndContent();
    initializeActionBar();
}

private void initializeLayoutAndContent() {
    dayPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dayImage);
    int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("dayPosition");
    day = dbAdapter.getAllDaysFromDb().get(id);

    dayOfMonth = day.getDayId();
    month = day.getMonthId();
    year = day.getYearId();
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    String imgPath = day.getPhotoPath();
    if (imgPath != null) {
        dayPhoto.setImageBitmap(PhotoUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(dayPhoto, imgPath));
    }
}
```

I just needed to move almost whole `initializeLayoutAndContent` method to `onWindowsFocusChanged` so data was initialized everytime with dayPhoto.

Comment: This is a hack, at best, and doesn't actually solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot load image in onCreate and I don't see any another solution.